# Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have the following error starting ApplicationContext in my SpringBoot application:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at es.ual.acg.cos.abstractcomponents.AbstractcomponentsApplication.main(AbstractcomponentsApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]

    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:37) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:80) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
... 14 common frames omitted
```

I have enabled Eureka Client with decorator `@EnableEurekaClient` in main class.

And I have configure .properties file with:

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
```

I use:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

First of all, I have run Eureka Server in other spring boot project (it works properly).

Note: this is the main class:

```
package es.ual.acg.cos.abstractcomponents;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"es.ual.acg.cos.abstractcomponents", "es.ual.acg.cos.util"})
@EnableEurekaClient
public class AbstractcomponentsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AbstractcomponentsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this issue? I seem to be experiencing the samething.

Answer (score 2):

If the application is for Eureka Client, then, **remove** the Eureka server dependency `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server`.

---

Reason:

In Eureka Client application, if there is an unwanted server dependency `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server`, this exact error can occur.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
.
.
```

However the reason for that could also be because of the failed bean creation (with stacktrace like below):

```
 Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
.
.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:436)
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/client/apache4/ApacheHttpClient4
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.Jersey1TransportClientFactories.newTransportClientFactory(Jersey1TransportClientFactories.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar:1.10.17]
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
.
.
```

Removing that dependency related to eureka server, and having only the client dependency `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` can potentially resolve this issue.

This scenario happened for me in Spring boot v2.7.8 (spring-cloud.version v2021.0.3).

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem,the reason for me is the version conflict.

my springboot version is 1.5.9.RELEASE,my project maven dependency is abort following:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.SR1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

the reason is because I introduce the httpcomponents and its version is 4.2.1 ,but is difference with the eureka introduced httpcomponents version(the version is httpclient/4.5.3 and httpcore/4.4.6,u can use mvn dependency:tree to check it),i thought is the reason 
that cause Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'.

and finally i changed the version of httpclient to 4.5.3 and httpcore to 4.4.6,then it works,I hope it helps you ^_^

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps, you use some other json deserialize dependencies. 
Jackson is default serialize dependency for spring cloud.

May be

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
  <actifactId>fastjson</actifactId>
</dependency>
```

I resolve this problem by deleting this dependency.